# Virtual Box Won't Accept .ISO To Install OS

Tags: virtualbox, windows-xp

I am trying to install a Virtual Machine, and every time I select the installation media I get this error:

```
Failed to open the CD/DVD image /home/jesse/Documents/Microsoft Windows Distribution ISO Archive/Microsoft.Windows.XP.Professional.ISO.
Could not get the storage format of the medium '/home/jesse/Documents/Microsoft Windows Distribution ISO Archive/Microsoft.Windows.XP.Professional.ISO' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: Medium
Interface: IMedium {53f9cc0c-e0fd-40a5-a404-a7a5272082cd}
Callee: IVirtualBox {c28be65f-1a8f-43b4-81f1-eb60cb516e66}
```

I would like too know how to fix this annoying error.

Comment: Are you mounting the ISO image by clicking on the Settings button?

Comment: I'd a similar message. I tried to modify a iso file adding a file ("DEBUG.EXE") to have a Virtual system (in DOS) with this file. For the true, I didn't finish the Linux part (I was using the Windows one), but I don't think that the problem is due to this. I must search the number for checksum that I didn't change and, so, it's wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure that you are choosing the right OS under the settings. (eg. Microsoft Windows, Windows XP) If that is correct try choosing "Unknown Windows" for the version.

Otherwise it is probably a bad or broken iso. Try re-downloading if possible.

Comment: Which one was it for you in the end? Broken ISO or the OS selection was wrong?

Comment: It was a broken iso most of the time. But it wouldn't hurt to check both.

Comment: Ah, indeed, it was for me too.

Comment: what worked for me was setting it up as a cd, not as hard disk. choosing live cd, and making sure the boot order was correct, and that optical drive (cd) was on.

Answer (score 7):

> Oracle VM VirtualBox is a program that allows you to create operating
>   systems on virtual machines, i.e. to use Windows programs on Linux. If
>   a program doesn't work under WINE, for example, it will probably work
>   in its native environment, Windows. Using VirtualBox would be a better
>   and easier alternative than installing a separate partition for
>   Windows on a Linux machine.<sup>**1**</sup>

Once installed, just look at the images below on how to choose your ISO file.  Once choosen, you ca go ahead and start the VM.  If the ISO is bad, or there is something wrong with it, you might want to verify it, by doing an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) for Linux. and [MD5SUM](http://www.pc-tools.net/win32/md5sums/) for Windows, otherwise, just download it again.

You can use an ISO file, or if you have burned the ISO to CD, choose Live CD/DVD.

Now when it comes to Windows, I have had some issues, when the ISO is not downloaded directly from Microsoft.  And just follow the guide below for step-by-step.

[image]
[image]
[image]

<sup>**1**</sup>[This WikiHow page](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-XP-on-Ubuntu-with-VirtualBox) has a complete step-by-step on how to do it.