# My computer cant read Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (Precise Pangolin) from CD-ROM

Tags: virtualbox, iso

I have an *emachines E525* I had to put the ISO on a blank disk and set the boot up USB CD-ROM and it does not see the CD, I tried the ISO on virtual box and it will not load it.

Failed to open the optical disk file `C:\Users\DONNA\Desktop\ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso`.

```
Could not get the storage format of the medium 'C:\Users\DONNA\Desktop\ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: Medium
Interface: IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Callee: IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something wrong with your .iso file.

Here is someone [with the same problem.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144780/virtual-box-wont-accept-iso-to-install-os)

You can Google how to check the MD5SUM of the file using Windows, or just re-download and burn a new disc.

Comment: thank you but the new iso i got for the 13.10 i ran it and its sating get the right kernel for my cpu

Comment: You've downloaded the i386 version, is your computer really 32 bit?  If not, try the x86 iso.  [More info here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64)

Also, in VirtualBox, make sure you are choosing the appropriate OS during that step(ie, Linux or Linux 64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the .iso file using Transmission to open the .torrent file and when it's complete right-click and force a recheck to make sure it's all there...  Then using Brasero/Xfburn/K3b burn the iso to disc at the slowest possible speed so the disc will run better and last longer...

Comment: what about cpu compatibility